# Play Framework - Get content from other site

Tags: scala, curl, playframework

I woundering it is possible to take content from other sites using play framework.

For example in php it is possible by using curl .

Example I have rute :

```
GET /test   controller.Aplicatin.getContent
```

and when I put in browser localhost:9000/test then it show content from example http://google.pl

And it is possible to send post data to other sites nad get content ?

For example by typing localhost:9000/test I wana send post username, password to gmail and return content from login page.

Answer (score 0):

You can do whatever you want in your controller Actions. Use the WS lib to make whatever type of request you want and then return that in html or whatever.

Example:

```
  def getContent = Action.async { implicit req =>
    WS.url("someurl.com").post("some body here").map(response => Ok(response.body))
  }
```